# NSFilemanager fileExistsAtPath always fails

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I used NSFilemanager class to check if file exists in my Mac OS folder. fileExistsAtPath always fails...help me to find my mistake. Thanks

```
 NSURL* finalImageURL;

 NSURL* imageURL = [[plistURL URLByDeletingPathExtension] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"png"];

 NSLog(@"Path: %@\n",imageURL.absoluteString); //Prints Path: /Users/MacAdmin/Desktop/gameover/sheet/SpriteSheet_GameOver-ipadhd.png

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imageURL.absoluteString])
{
   printf("Exists\n");
}
```

Comment: Seems weird to print out imageURL.relativePath,[imageURL path] but then use imageURL.absoluteString. Maybe you should print out imageURL.absoluteString.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Prints `Path: /Users/Gururaj/Desktop/gameover/sheet/SpriteSheet_GameOver-ipadhd.png`

Are you sure? It seems that you're trying to use the absolute string representation of the URL, along with the `file://` schema at its beginning. Try changing `absoluteString` to `path`.

Comment: The comment is left over from an earlier version of the question whose code might have actually printed that (although that NSLog statement had a couple of other things wrong with it).